# Statistics show ,that ....recent figures show,that

Tags: translation

I had a test where i needed to translate from German to English . Can u say "statistics show,that ..." ?

And the other sentence which was marked as wrong : " Recent figures show, that London is growing faster than other regions"

I cannot find my mistake in here ?

Comment: You're probably talking about a clause beginning with *daß* in German, which obeys different rules from what English is used to.

Comment: Questions regarding translation or comparisons between two languages are probably off-topic. On the English side, we don't understand how you decided on the examples given. A German example with a description on how you decided on the English example given might be helpful to understand the real issues.

Comment: First one was :" statistiken zeigen,dass.... " translated with :"statistics show,  that" . So the comma of course is wrong but apart of That?

Answer (score 2):

The mistake lies in the use of the comma. Never place a comma between subject and verb (unless the subject contains a parenthetical modifier such as an apposition), or between verb and object.

Your sentences should have read as follows:

- Statistics **show that** ...
- Recent figures **show that** ...